# run "%run" command from string

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to ask how to run in Jupyter Notebook the `%run` command. So say I have another notebook I want to run in parall called notebook.ipynb. However, I want to call this command to the notebook name from string. So I want something like this:

```
name = 'notebook.ipynb'
exec("%run "+name)
```

This results in an error.

How can I overcome this?
Thanks

Comment: what error? exec executes python script and that doesn't seem like one so I don't know much about Jupyter but You may have to use `os.system(f'%run {name}')` (first `import os`) this runs it from cmd on windows tho don't know about other os

Comment: `%run` is not Python, it's a Jupyter thing, so it makes no sense to the interpreter if you try to `exec` it. Look instead at the way to do what you want in Python. It's called the `subprocess` module.

Comment: I get the following error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-7-13fcb148f6bc>", line 1, in <module>
    exec('%run construct_mono.ipynb')

  File "<string>", line 1
    %run construct_mono.ipynb
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: I tried the following using subprocess: ```import subprocess
subprocess.run("construct_mono.ipynb")``` but it gives me an error as well. I just want to run the entire notebook in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

So in the end it wasn't `submodule` that I was after.

I just needed to use `$` to evaluate Python variable for Jupyter magic function.

`notebook_name = 'construct_Test.ipynb'`

`%run $notebook_name`

Thanks